# Remember me checkbox functionality in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, checkbox

How to add "Remember Me" Login Functionality?

Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Margin="70,50,70,50"  Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Name="txtName"/>
        <PasswordBox Name="txtPassword"/>
        <Button Tap="Button_Tap"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Margin="70,430">
            <CheckBox Name="cbStayIn" Content="StayIn"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When User checked in StayIn checkbox it should hold values of name and password.

Give Me Suggestion.

Comment: Be more specific. Which part particularly you are having trouble with?

Comment: @ haro7 what actual i want to know that , When user click on login button, check if cbstayin is checked == true then txtname and txtpassword hold it value with cookie or viewstate etc.

Comment: You can try using [`IsolatedStorageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to persist simple key-value pair throughout application restart (the value will be there still after apps closed and reopened).

Comment: @ har07 I want to make like this(see the link):http://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/276/Default.aspx it,s possible with Isolated storage?

Comment: yes, it is possible with Isolated Storage

Comment: @ har07 I am using this but not work my code is:

Comment: Page load:InitializeComponent();
   if (cbStayIn.IsChecked == true)
   {
      string Email = (string)userSettings["email"];
      txtName.Text = Email;
      string Password = (string)userSettings["password"];
      txtPassword.Password = Password;
    }

Comment: button tap:private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
           userSettings.Add("email", txtName.Text);
           userSettings.Add("password", txtPassword.Password);
        }

Comment: instead of posting codes in comment, you supposed to post it in the question (edit the question to include the latest code you tried with proper formatting). Anyway, check my answer..

Answer (score 0):

Responding your comment, it seems that the logic is a bit off. Your checkbox will be in it's default state regardless user checked it or not the last time he logged in. Try this way :

```
//on page load :
InitializeComponent(); 

//check if remember me checked the last time user login
bool stayin = false;
userSettings.TryGetValue<bool>("stayin", stayin);

//if checked, load username & password from iso store
if (stayin) 
{ 
    string Email = (string)userSettings["email"]; 
    txtName.Text = Email; 
    string Password = (string)userSettings["password"]; 
    txtPassword.Password = Password; 
}

......

//on login button clicked
private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) 
{ 
    //if remember me checked,
    //save mail, password, and stayin = true in iso store
    if (cbStayIn.IsChecked == true) 
    {
        userSettings.Add("email", txtName.Text); 
        userSettings.Add("password", txtPassword.Password); 
        userSettings.Add("stayin", true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: @ har07 code not work properly. Give error like:An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. My code is above.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage; 

namespace iso
{

public partial class LoginPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    private IsolatedStorageSettings userSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bool stayin = false;
       // userSettings.TryGetValue<bool>("stayin", stayin);
        userSettings.TryGetValue<bool>("stayin", out stayin);
        if (stayin)
        {
            string Email = (string)userSettings["email"];
            txtName.Text = Email;
            string Password = (string)userSettings["password"];
            txtPassword.Password = Password;
        }
    }
    private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbStayIn.IsChecked == true)
        {
            userSettings.Add("email", txtName.Text);// Error :An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
            userSettings.Add("password", txtPassword.Password);
            userSettings.Add("stayin", true);
        }

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code helps. dint compile the code, pardon the compilation Errors

```
 If(checkbox.Selected == true)
    {
        //check if the UserName and PassWord are already stored
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("userName"))
    {
      UserName.Text = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userName"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["userName"] = UserNameTextBox.Text;
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }
    if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("Password"))
    {
      PasswordBox.Text = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Password"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Password"] = PasswordBox.Text;
       IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
    }     
    }
```

Comment: can you give me more context of what problem you are facing?

Comment: it gives error like:An item with the same key has already been added.

Answer (score 0):

public LoginPage()

{

```
InitializeComponent();
    if (cbStayIn.IsChecked == true)
    {
        if (userSettings.Contains("Name"))
            {
                txtName.Text = userSettings["Name"].ToString();
            }

            if (userSettings.Contains("Password"))
            {
                txtPassword.Password = userSettings["Password"].ToString();
            }
    }
```

}

private void Button_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)

{
        //
    try
        {
            if ((userSettings.Contains("UserName")) == false)
                {
                    userSettings.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
                }

```
            if ((userSettings.Contains("Pass")) == false)
            {
                userSettings.Add("Password", txtPassword.Password);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: @Baradi:it gives error like:An item with the same key has already been added.

Comment: what is userSettings here?

Comment: okay got it, in the constructor you are checking for userSettings.Contains("Name"), but in the button tap you are checking for (userSettings.Contains("UserName")) which does not exist then the userSettings.Add("Name", txtName.Text);  executes every time. so if it executes the first time, it wont throw you the error, but for the second time when it executes, the key "Name" already exists and you are adding it for the second time. so it will throw the key already exists error.

Comment: @Baradi: Help me to slove this issue.